# why templated non const parameter constructor is preferred to given copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++17, variant, requirements

I want to make my class be able to be used in a `std::variant`.

The simply code that should work is:

```
int main()
{
    std::variant< int, A > v;

    A a(1);
    v = a;
}
```

My class contains a templated constructor:

```
 template <typename T> A( T& );
```

At this point the trouble starts! The constructor binds to the call from `std::variant` and not the provided `A(const A&)` is used anymore.

For copy&paste reasons the full example here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

class A
{
    private:
        int x;

    public:

        A( A&&) {}
        A( const A& ) {}
        A(){}
        ~A() {}

        A& operator=( const A& ) { return *this;}
        A& operator=( A&& ) {return *this;}

        template <typename T>
            A( T& t  ) 
            {
                std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
            }

        A(int _x):x{_x}{}
};

int main()
{
    std::variant< int, A > v;

    A a(1);
    v = a;
}
```

Background:

Why the template here?
The problem starts while using a constructor which takes a serializer type. The serializer can have multiple types, depends on files or streams to serialize with.

Remark: I know that the functionality of the constructors is missing!

Comment: Re your question about your own code, "Why the template here?", where did you get this code?

Comment: Re "the requirement of A(A&); for using a class as a element of std::variant", there is no such requirement.

Comment: **−1** Missing **required headers**.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: done ;)

Comment: Thanks. Removed the minus 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with `std::variant`. The problem is with the constructor template,

```
template <typename T>
A(T& t)
```

Such constructors are problematic because when the argument is a non-`const` lvalue of type `A`, this constructor is preferred over the copy constructor taking `const A&`---which is usually not the intended behaviour. To prevent this, we usually constrain this constructor with SFINAE:

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, A>>>
A(T& t)  // or T&& t
```

and might consider making it `explicit` as well.

We usually do not provide copy constructors taking non-`const` `A&`, since they are redundant next to the ones taking `const A&`.

Comment: A templated constructor with a parameter which is not const is preferred over a fully matching "hand crafted" version? Wow!

Comment: @Klaus yes because a non-const lvalue prefers to bind to a non-const lvalue reference instead of a const lvalue reference. However, the templatedness is considered at a later stage of overload resolution.

Comment: @Klaus: As I recall the rules changed slightly from C++03 to C++11.